# How can I restrict user from not to select more than three checkbox of cell of TableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I'm populating 10 elements on tableView. I'm giving checkbox for selecting element, now I want to restrict user from not select more than three elements of tableViewCell. How can I do that?

```
`- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return self.data.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.textLabel.text = [self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a NSUInteger Variable as CheckMarkcount.

```
@interface ViewController ()
{

  NSUInteger CheckMarkcount;

}

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    CheckMarkcount = 0;
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
       cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
       if(CheckMarkcount>0)
           CheckMarkcount--;
   }
   else {

      if(CheckMarkcount<3)
      {
         cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
         CheckMarkcount++;
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But it's not working properly, according to your code it's allowing to checkmark only one cell.

Comment: Can u send your code what u have implemented ... 
Because it works f9 here i have used the same. I have checked just now

Comment: I want to allow user to select max 3 checkbox after that user won't be able to select.

Comment: Replace your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method with my didSelectRowAtIndexPath and declare the  NSUInteger CheckMarkcount

Comment: Ur Welcome happy to help you

Answer (score -1):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];



    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
    {

        if(count <3)
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            count = count + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            //alert
            NSLog(@"greater then 3");
        }


    }

    else
    {
        if(count>1)
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            count--;
        }
        else
        {
            //show alert
            NSLog(@"choose only 1");
        }

    }


    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: yes. Brother according to your code after selecting all checkbox while unselecting it is showing "choose only 1" msg.

Comment: @Abhishek Suryawanshi what was the problem in my code

Comment: it is allowing to select all cells. I want restriction so that user won't be able to select more than three cells checkbox.